# The json file displays the wrong format

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, format

I'm using ajax to write json files. But the file display format is not correct.

AJAX:

```
$.ajax
      ({
          type: "GET",
          dataType : 'json',
          contentType: "application/json",
          async: false,
          url: 'save_json.php',
          data: { 
            data: JSON.stringify(data) 
          },
          success: function () {alert("Thanks!"); },
          failure: function() {alert("Error!");}
      });
```

SAVE_JSON.PHP:

```
<?php
$myFile = "profile.json";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_GET["data"];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh)
?>
```

It shows the following:

```
{"profile":[{"no":1,"firstName":"C","lastName":"D","age":25,"sex":"M","country":"US","phoneNumber":"019878736729","email":"johnsmith@example.com"},{"no":2,"firstName":"A","lastName":"B","age":28,"sex":"M","country":"VN","phoneNumber":"84928374839","email":"nguyentam@example.com"}]}
```

But i want to display with correct format as follows:

```
{
"profile": [
    {
        "no": 1,
        "firstName": "C",
        "lastName": "D",
        "age": 25,
        "sex": "M",
        "country": "US",
        "phoneNumber": "019878736729",
        "email": "johnsmith@example.com"
    },
    {
        "no": 2,
        "firstName": "A",
        "lastName": "B",
        "age": 28,
        "sex": "M",
        "country": "VN",
        "phoneNumber": "84928374839",
        "email": "nguyentam@example.com"
    }
]
```

}

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Your format is correct; a raw JSON file doesn't have any line breaks. It will still be perfectly readable by your scripts. If you'd like to see it in a more human-readable format, use `print_r` or `var_dump` in your PHP.

Comment: Can be more specific?

Comment: `contentType: "application/json",` makes no sense. You're making a GET request, there is no request body to describe the content type of. (For that matter, why are you making a GET request? The endpoint is writing to a file on the server, that's a job for PUT not GET).

Answer (score 2):

Let's be clear about the two parts in this and what each part is doing.

1. Your JavaScript file is taking an object ("data") and turning it into a JSON string with the call to `JSON.stringify()`. It is then sending it to your PHP server.
2. Your PHP server is saving a string to the file. It isn't handling this string as a JSON string at all - it doesn't care.

You have a bunch of approaches how you can handle this. You can, for example, turn the string back into an object on the PHP side and dump out the formatted version:

```
$obj = json_decode($string_data,true);
$formatted_json = json_encode($obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
fwrite($fh, $formatted_json);
```

You could also do this formatting on the JavaScript side, replacing your call to `JSON.stringify()` with one with additional parameters:

```
JSON.stringify(data,null,4)
```

The *null* indicates that you're not going to use a replacer function, while the *4* is how many spaces to indent the pretty printing.

Which method you use is up to you and how much bandwidth you want to use (sending the formatted version takes up more space).

Keep in mind, however, that JSON parsers don't use this extra space - it is all formatting to help you (or some other human) read it.

(And @Quentin raises an excellent point in the comments to your question - using "GET" is a bad idea in this case for a lot of reasons. Switch to "PUT" or, at worst, "POST".)